# What does this command mean and what functions performs?

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, opencms

In [this](http://documentation.opencms.org/opencms-documentation/introduction/getting-opencms/) tutorial I read about this command- `-Djava.awt.headless=true` From text I don't understand role of this command. In Tomcat's documentation I didn't find anything about it. Where should I use and enter it?

Comment: Refer to documentation at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you execute the following command:

```
java -h
```

You can see the help of the `java` command.

And you can find that:

> [...]
>
> `-D<name>=<value> set a system property`
>
> [...]

So it means that you defined a new system property with name `java.awt.headless` and value `true`.

You can find some additional information related to this variable (`java.awt.headless`) on this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) where is stated that:

> You can also use the following command line if you plan to run the same application in both a headless and a traditional environment:
>
> `java -Djava.awt.headless=true`

Note:

> **Headless mode** is a system configuration in which the display device, keyboard, or mouse is lacking. Sounds unexpected, but actually you can perform different operations in this mode, even with graphic data.

---

Set system properties on tomcat.

If you have tomcat 7 you can edit the following file

```
<TOMCAT DIRECTORY>/conf/catalina.properties
```

and add the property `java.awt.headless`. Also other versions of tomcat can use the same file to set a system property.

Comment: I used command java -Djava.awt.headless=true and got a help-list with the link to javaSE documentation.http://postimg.org/image/6aqdmnemp/  I think there is somthing worng...

Comment: The command java needs at least a class or an executable jar to start. -D<variable>=<value> simply adds a parameter, but the command need to be completed

Comment: @lga that is because it's not a command by itself - you have to also at least specify the name of the class that you want to run. Example: `java -Djava.awt.headless=true com.mypackage.MyProgram`

Comment: now I understand. but what class should I specify in order to start Tomcat's JVM with the command line(how it is written in the guide, which was shown in my question)?

Comment: Which version of tomcat are you using?